# ImageDataGenerator with additional text input

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The architecture I'm trying to implement is here:
[Patient-data adapted model architecture: ResNet-50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky5Cq.png). My images are split into folders by labels as such:

```
root/
    ├── train/
    │   ├── class1/
    │   ├── class2/
    │   ...
    │
    └── validation/
       ├── class1/
       ├── class2/
       ...
```

I also have a CSV file that contains the image name, image labels (an image can have multiple class labels) and additional information:

```
+--------+---------------+-------+------+
| File  |    Labels     | Info1 | Info2 |
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+
| 1.png | class1        | 0.512 |     1 |
| 2.png | class2        |   0.4 |     0 |
| 3.png | class1|class2 |  0.64 |     1 |
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

My network model has two inputs, one which will be used to process the image and another one which will concatenate to the final layer before the dense layer:

```py
input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 1)

img_input= Input(input_shape)
vec_input = Input((2,))

res = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(img_input)

# Processing ...

res = Flatten()(res)
res = Concatenate()([res, vec_input])
res = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='fc' + str(classes))(res)
```

To get the images I am using ImageDataGenerator with flow_from_directory, which works fine for getting only the image data:

```py
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(target_size, target_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=class_mode,
        color_mode=color_mode)

# Similarly for the train data generator ...

# Train the model using above defined data generators
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

I now need to use the additional information for each image as the vec_input in my model. I have looked at using flow_from_dataframe and creating custom generators, but am unsure how to go about this. I can restructure the images by putting them in the same folder if needed, although then I suppose I cannot use flow_from_directory. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

EDIT:

In case somebody needs a solution, here's what I've been able to come up with:

```
class CustomSequenceGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, image_dir, csv_file_path, label_path, dim=448, batch_size=8,
                 n_classes=15, n_channels=1, vec_size=3, shuffle=True):
        # Keras generator
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.image_file_list = os.listdir(image_dir)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.dim = dim
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.vec_size = vec_size
        self.labels = get_class_labels(label_path)
        self.labels_dict = dict(zip(self.labels, range(0, len(self.labels))))

        self.csv_file.set_index('File', inplace=True, drop=True)

    def __len__(self):
        """It is mandatory to implement it on Keras Sequence"""
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_file_list) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        # Generate indexes of the batch
        samples = self.image_file_list[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        x, y = self.__data_generation(samples, index)
        return x, y

    def __data_generation(self, samples, start_index):

        x_batch_image = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.dim, self.dim, self.n_channels))
        x_batch_vector = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.vec_size))
        y_batch = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))
        self.csv_file.reindex()
        for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
            image_file_path = self.image_dir + "/" + sample
            image = self.preprocess_image(Image.open(image_file_path), 448)

            features, labels = self.preprocess_csv(self.csv_file, sample, self.labels_dict, self.n_classes)
            x_batch_image[i] = image
            x_batch_vector[i] = features
            y_batch[i] = labels

        return [x_batch_image, x_batch_vector], y_batch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to implement a custom [`Sequence` object](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence), potentially inheriting the methods of `ImageDataGenerator`. Maybe what you need doesn't require all the complexity of `ImageDataGenerator` (i.e. random transforms, image saving, interpolation) and in this case you wouldn't need to inherit it.